# Correlation in text using R

Tags: r, text, correlation

My data looks like (example)

```
ID     Col1     Col2
1232   ABCSD    abd
2342   ABCSD    esw
7643   ABCSD    rty
9821   ETHS     fvc
```

I have `2845428` such rows. I want to find out how correlated each pair in `Col1` and `Col2` is. For example

```
ABCSD     abd     0.64
ETHS      fvc     0.23
```

How can I go about it using R? Thanks

Comment: Your desired output doesn't make any sense in relation to your example data. How did you get the values 0.64 and 0.23 from your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by correlation you mean something like "what portion of the ABCSD observations have abd in Col2..."

If your data are in a dataframe named df,

```
#get the absolute frequency
freqs <- ftable(df[,2:3])  

#convert to relative frequency
freqs <- freqs/rowSums(freqs)

#then to get the format you want
library(reshape)
freqs <- melt(freqs)
```